# Angular ng-repeat inside tr, breaks the cascading dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I'm using angular 1.4.8 version.
I'm using array of strings, to iterate over table using ng-repeat, and three have cascading dropdown.
Issue is : 
on row 0: I populate the selection and when I get onto row1, I make  different selection, the pre-selected ones on row0, gets changed.

```
have checked on [$index] property too
```

Js fiddle link here

https://jsfiddle.net/sprakashg/vct4wcab/

Comment: seems to work here, can you describe exactly what selections you make in what order and what the unexpected result is?

Comment: Sure Nick, Please click on the link now. You would see three drop-downs. Select the first drop-down, 'Ethnic Wear', second drop-down gets populated based on the first selection, now select 'sarees', third drop-down gets populated based on first and second selection.In the second row, select 'Ethnic Wear' again, followed by in the second drop-down select 'skirts', you would see the previous row last drop-down gets changed and the third row is pre-populated already and third row too

Comment: thanks for the test case, I tried to explain it as thoroughly as possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement isolated directive concept to achieve the same. Actually your scenario is ideal for isolated directive implementation. Also it is advisable to keep all the datasource and logic inside service instead of controller. I created sample implementation to demonstrate the same.

Plunkar - https://plnkr.co/edit/92hxBy2zGGsQLAsf3ZWE?p=preview

Hope this will help!

Directive -

```
app.directive("product", function(productService) {
  return {
    templateUrl: "loadTableData.html",
    replace: true,
    scope: {
      product: '='
    },
    link: function($scope) {
      $scope.productCategory = productService.getProductCategory();
      $scope.productSubCategory = function(index, field) {
        $scope.subType = productService.getProductSubCategory($scope.productCategory[field]);
      };
      $scope.productType = function(index, parent, field) {
        $scope.pType = productService.getProductType($scope.productCategory[parent], $scope.subType[field]);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

loadTableData.html

```
<tr>
  <td>{{product.sku}}</td>
  <td><img ng-src='{{product.image}}'></td>
  <td>
    <select ng-options='k as v for (k,v) in productCategory' ng-change='productSubCategory($index, item.check1)' ng-model='item.check1'>
      <option value='' disabled>Select Product Category</option>
    </select>
  </td>
  <td>
    <select ng-model='item.check2' ng-options='a as b for (a,b) in subType' ng-change='productType($index, item.check1, item.check2)'>
      <option value='' disabled>Select Product Sub-Category</option>
    </select>
  </td>
  <td>
    <select ng-model='item.check3' ng-options='c as d for (c,d) in pType'>
      <option value='' disabled>Select Product Type</option>
    </select>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Usage:

```
<tbody>
        <tr data-ng-repeat="item in products" class="text-center" product="item">
</tbody>
```

Product Service:

```
app.service('productService', function() {
  var productCategory = [
    'Bags',
    'Shoes',
    'Western Wear',
    'Ethnic Wear',
    'Accessories',
    'Home & Decor',
  ];

  this.getProducts = function() {
    return [{
      "sku": "FSLPEW0086",
      "image": "http://imgprd.styletagassets.com/FSLPEW0086_1.jpg?resize=110px:139px"
    }, {
      "sku": "FSLPEW0087",
      "image": "http://imgprd.styletagassets.com/FTTPEW0085_1.jpg?resize=110px:139px"
    }, {
      "sku": "FSLPEW0089",
      "image": "http://imgprd.styletagassets.com/FSLPEW0084_1.jpg?resize=110px:139px"
    }];
  }

  this.getProductCategory = function() {
    return productCategory;
  }

  this.getProductSubCategory = function(productCategoryName) {
    console.log(productCategoryName)
    var subType = [];
    if (productCategoryName == 'Ethnic Wear') {
      subType = [
        "Kurtas",
        "Kurtis",
        "Anarkalis",
        "Suits",
        "Churidars",
        "Salwars",
        "Palazzos",
        "Skirts",
        "Sarees"
      ]
    } else if (productCategoryName == 'Skirts') {

    }
    return subType;
  }

  this.getProductType = function(productCategoryName, subCategoryName) {
    console.log(productCategoryName)
    console.log(subCategoryName)
    var pType = [];
    if ((productCategoryName == 'Ethnic Wear') && (subCategoryName == 'Sarees')) {
      pType = [
        "Traditional Sarees",
        "Occassionwear Sarees",
        "Bollywood Sarees",
        "Bandhani & Bandhej Sarees",
        "Lehenga Sarees",
        "Dailywear Sarees",
        "Printed Sarees"
      ];
    } else if ((productCategoryName == 'Ethnic Wear') && (subCategoryName == 'Skirts')) {
      pType = [
        "Skirts"
      ]
    } else if ((productCategoryName == 'Ethnic Wear') && (subCategoryName == 'Palazzos')) {
      pType = [
        "Palazzos",
        "Culottes"
      ]
    } else if ((productCategoryName == 'Ethnic Wear') && (subCategoryName == 'Salwars')) {
      pType = [
        "Salwars",
        "Patiala",
        "Patiala & Dupatta Sets",
        "Harem Pants",
        "Jodhpuris",
        "Dhoti Salwars"
      ]
    }
    return pType;
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks sumit, I will go through the implementation

Comment: Its my pleasure :) Hope this will help to solve your issue.

Comment: Hi Sumit, thank you so much for timely help. I have followed an approach and I have arrived solving this issue. Below is the link where I have implemented this, please have a look and let me know, where I could have done it, even better jsfiddle.net/vct4wcab/6

Comment: Hi Sumit, I have never written my own directive for solving an issue.

Comment: @SumitDeshpande : How to implement this same Scenario for angular 4 ..?Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**The problem** is that you keep the possible options a user can choose from in a `$scope` variable. This `$scope` variable is shared for every row in the table, so if you change for example `$scope.subTpe` or `$scope.pType` it will be a global change. Now, because Angular has 2-way data binding, if it sees a change in the this `$scope` variables, it will re-render all the items that depend on it, i.e. all the other dropdowns in the other rows too.

For example:

```
<select ng-options = "k as v for (k,v) in productCategory" 
        ng-change  = "productSubCategory($index, item.check1)" 
        ng-model   = "item.check1">
```

the variable `productCategory` refers to the `$scope.productCategory` that is thus referring to the global `$scope`. The `ng-change` will trigger a change in the `$scope` so that it will be changed for all dropdown boxes. The value in contrary has the correct binding, it's binding refers to item and item is different in every row.

Every time you change a dropdown, e.g.:

```
$scope.pType = [ "Skirts" ]
```

you are affecting the whole `$scope` and thus all dropdowns.

**To fix** this you will have to keep track of every list in every row and every column. So you will have to keep a data structure with for each row and column the dropdown items that have to be shown. So what you need is something like this:

```
item.possibleProductCategoriesToChooseFrom
item.possibleSubcategoriesToChooseFrom
item.possibleProductTypesToChooseFrom
```

So that your `ng-options` changes to something like this:

```
<select ng-options = "k as v for (k,v) in item.possibleProductCategoriesToChooseFrom" 
        ng-change  = "productSubCategory($index, item)" 
        ng-model   = "item.check1">
```

remark that you have to pass the full item to the change listener, in order to be able to set the possible items to choose from on the item.

In your change listeners you want to set the correct list of possible values the user can choose from, for example:

```
item.possibleProductTypesToChooseFrom = [ "Skirts" ];
```

It gets a little bit complex because there is a lot of dynamic building going on in the page, but there is no other way to do it since you have to keep state of all the dropdown components in your page.

Comment: Thanks Nick. I'm working on the datastructure, but bit confused how to map them using ng-options, because it has to be cascading dropdowns, based on one select populate another and from another to another .

Comment: If you just follow my proposed solution it should work out. Did you get a grasp on it or would you prefer a working example?

Comment: Hi Nick, thank you so much for timely help.  I have followed your proposed approach and I have arrived solving this issue.   Below is the link where I have implemented this, please have a look and let me know, where I could have done it even better https://jsfiddle.net/vct4wcab/6/

Comment: @NickVanderhoven : how to implement this same scenario in angular 4 ?